# Why isn't this inverse Fourier transform giving the correct results?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, fft

I want to invert the Fourier transform of an image in MATLAB, but the result is not the original image (as it should be). There is obviously some implementation detail that I don't know about that's causing the issue. Here's the code:

```
img = imread('img.jpg');
fft = fft2(img);
inv = ifft2(fft);
imshow(inv);
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since [`fft2`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft2.html) and [`ifft2`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ifft2.html) both perform calculations in either [`double`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.html) or [`single`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/single.html) precision, your [image data](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/image-types.html) (which is likely of type [`uint8`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uint8.html)) gets converted to type `double` first before being processed by `fft2`. You will therefore have to convert your output image `inv` back to an unsigned 8-bit integer using the function [`uint8`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uint8.html) to recover the original image:

```
>> img = imread('peppers.png');  % Load a sample image
>> fft = fft2(img);   % Get the Fourier transform
>> inv = ifft2(fft);  % Get the inverse Fourier transform
>> inv = uint8(inv);  % Convert to uint8
>> imshow(inv);       % Show the image
>> isequal(img, inv)  % Test if inv matches the original image img

ans =

     1                % It does!
```

**NOTE:** As an additional tip, I would avoid naming your variables `fft` and `inv` since functions with those names already exist in MATLAB.

Answer (score 3):

Also if you are trying to do FFT on color (24-bit) image - note that imread() will return M  x N x 3 array. So you should perform FFT on each R/G/B channel separately.

[See this](http://www.dsprelated.com/groups/matlab/show/3769.php) for detail.

Comment: Actually, it appears that FFT2 handles that for you. If you type `type fft2` into the Command Window, you can see that a 3-D input `x` results in the operation `fft(fft(x,[],2),[],1)`, which performs an FFT across the second then first dimension, while a 2-D input `x` (if you were passing each color plane separately) results in a call to [FFTN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fftn.html). Comparing each method, the maximum absolute pixel-wise difference between the results is around 5.6e-10, likely due to differences in the order of operations. In short, the two are nearly equivalent.