# MatLab - IFFT of an image is complex

Tags: matlab, fft, ifft

I'm taking the `fft2` of an image which gives me a complex matrix, but when I transform it back with `ifft2` the result is also a complex matrix and it is not the original image. What can be happening here?

```
image=('file.png');
F_image=fft2(moon);
IF_image=ifft2(F_image);
```

Comment: `ifft2` will return complex data even if original data in `fft2` was real due to round-off errors. use `ifft2(F_image,'symmetric')` see documentation in matlab carefully

Comment: Ok, that forces the output to be real but I don't get the original image.

Comment: Can't you just remove the imaginary part of `IF_image`? It will be very small, and you know it's caused only by round-off errors

Comment: The problem was actually in my input file. Thanks.

Comment: It's part of the small floating point imprecision when dealing with the FFT.  If you know for a fact that your data is real, simply use `real` to obtain the real parts of your image.  I also tell you to do that in my post to your previous question shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25827916/matlab-shifting-an-image-using-fft/25830410#25830410

Comment: Your answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3729235/why-isnt-this-inverse-fourier-transform-giving-the-correct-results

Answer (score 0):

Due to approximation, output of IFFT has imaginary parts, but their magnitude will be too low. You can just ignore them, you will get almost same image.

```
img = imread("c.jpg");
img_gray = rgb2gray(img);
imgfft = fft2(double(img_gray));
opimg = uint8(real(ifft2(imgfft)));
```